# Вычитание списка чисел от элементов матрицы

Tags: python, матрицы, numpy

Есть координатная сетка:

```
x = np.arange(-1,1.1,0.7)
y = np.arange(-1,1.1,0.7)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x,y)

#Результат для X

 [[-1.  -0.3  0.4  1.1]
  [-1.  -0.3  0.4  1.1]
  [-1.  -0.3  0.4  1.1]
  [-1.  -0.3  0.4  1.1]]
```

и лист:

```
RX = [0, 0.1, 0.2]
```

Необходимо каждый элемент матрицы отнять от этого листа:

```
print(result_array)
  [[[-1. , -1.1, -1.2]
    [-0.3, -0.4, -0.5]
    [ 0.4,  0.3,  0.2]
    [ 1.1,  1. ,  0.9]]

   [[-1. , -1.1, -1.2]
    [-0.3, -0.4, -0.5]
    [ 0.4,  0.3,  0.2]
    [ 1.1,  1. ,  0.9]]

   [[-1. , -1.1, -1.2]
    [-0.3, -0.4, -0.5]
    [ 0.4,  0.3,  0.2]
    [ 1.1,  1. ,  0.9]]

   [[-1. , -1.1, -1.2]
    [-0.3, -0.4, -0.5]
    [ 0.4,  0.3,  0.2]
    [ 1.1,  1. ,  0.9]]
```

Каким образом можно это реализовать? Через деление каждой строки на отдельные элементы? Если есть вариант реализации через numpy - будет отлично.

Update: еще нужно просумировать элементы в каждой отдельной ячейке.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
np.repeat(x, len(x)*len(RX)).reshape(len(x),len(x),len(RX)).transpose(1,0,2) - \
np.tile(RX, len(x)**2).reshape(len(x),len(x),len(RX))
```

Результат:

```
array([[[-1. , -1.1, -1.2],
        [-0.3, -0.4, -0.5],
        [ 0.4,  0.3,  0.2],
        [ 1.1,  1. ,  0.9]],

       [[-1. , -1.1, -1.2],
        [-0.3, -0.4, -0.5],
        [ 0.4,  0.3,  0.2],
        [ 1.1,  1. ,  0.9]],

       [[-1. , -1.1, -1.2],
        [-0.3, -0.4, -0.5],
        [ 0.4,  0.3,  0.2],
        [ 1.1,  1. ,  0.9]],

       [[-1. , -1.1, -1.2],
        [-0.3, -0.4, -0.5],
        [ 0.4,  0.3,  0.2],
        [ 1.1,  1. ,  0.9]]])
```

Comment: Не совсем, необходимо отнять лист RX от КАЖДОГО элемента матрицы, то есть в одной строке матрицы будет 5 листов размера RX.

Comment: @AleksandrAleksandrov, может стоит привести пример матрицы поменьше и указать выходную матрицу в полном объеме. Пока что не очень понятно, что вы ожидаете получить на выходе...

Comment: Правки внес, матрицу и список сделал меньше. Там еще одно дополнительно условие в конце дописал.

Comment: @AleksandrAleksandrov, я исправил ответ. По поводу второго вопроса: `просумировать элементы в каждой отдельной ячейке` - лучше задать отдельный вопрос и (как всегда) указать выходную / результирующую матрицу

Comment: Ответ близко, но для наглядности я подправил ожидаемый ответ в описании. По сути, нужный мне результат - это в каждая матрица в вашем ответе была [ [-1. , -1.1, -1.2],[-0.3, -0.4, -0.5], [ 0.4,  0.3,  0.2]],[ 1.1,  1. ,  0.9]]

Comment: @AleksandrAleksandrov, вы можете добавить выходную матрицу в виде Numpy array в вопрос? Т.е. запостить еще и результат `print(result_array)` в вопрос? Какой размерности (`shape`) должна быть выходная матрица?

Comment: Правки в описание внес. np.tile выдает нули у меня вместо вашего результата.